# compatability issue with windows xp

Tags: c#, .net

I have already finished designing my c sharp application using visual studio 2010.The target framework is .NET framework 4.0 client profile.The application worked perfectly on my machine which runs windows 7- 32bit and on other windows 7 machines,but it gives error while working on windows xp machines.one friend advanced me to change the target framework to .NET framework 2.0,and I did already but the problem is the same (error on windows xp)and additionally the application gives error on windows 7.....what is the solution??
Note: I don't have installer for my project

Comment: You need to post code! And say what the error is!

Comment: I can not post the code because it is a huge project...the error is "Old format or invalid type library"

Comment: Did you do a search for your error?

Comment: yes,and most of my search results advanced my to make an installer to my project and include the .NET version required

Answer (score 2):

> I don't have installer for my project

This is likely the problem.  You most likely just need to make an installer which will install all of your programs dependencies, which includes the .NET Framework if it's not installed, but potentially other libraries you may be using.

.NET 4 and earlier versions are compatible with Windows XP and Windows 7, provided the frameworks are installed properly.

Comment: My visual studio 2010 does not have installer maker and I don't have an idea about adding it to my studio because I'm new in programming .

Comment: @Boulis You can use a third party installer. WiX is common, but there's also Inno, etc.  Any google search will turn up many options.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before with Windows XP/7, beside change the framework to .Net 2.0. You should also check if the platform target is: X86. To do this, right click project and go to Build Tab. This fix my issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: I checked it,and it is already X86